# How to know an object of the scrollview is on the top in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

Please let me know, how to get notified when a particular subview of the scroll view reached at the top of the view.

Its like when a section of the table reached at the top it stops to go up from view.

I want same functionality, because I need to add two views into the scrollview and want to get notified when the first object reached at the top.

Comment: implement scrollview delegate methods, there you can detect scrolling position

Comment: Do want to make sticky header using UIScrollView?

Comment: @iWheelBuy, Yes like android.

Comment: @GopalDevra why don't you want to use UITableView?

Comment: @iWheelBuy, I tried but it is getting reloading section always when I try to click on the button of the section of table view.

My section is containing another tableview.

Comment: @GopalDevra mastering UITableView is a vital thing in iOS development. I'd suggest to solve reloading problem and use UITableView. It has benefits over UIScrollView because of cell reusing

Comment: Ok, thanks @iWheelBuy, I am trying.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Position of the View or add a UIView add the Top
and use the scrollView.delegate to check intersects with the upper frame